# How to retrieve last track row for each user in another table? It has two tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables

Table A has `usr_id , usr_name , usr_status [1 or 0]`

Table B has `id , usr_id,tracked_date [Each user can track multiple time]`

Need to get last track of each user has `usr_status = 1`

How to achieve through mysql query ?

Tried like:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    tableb b
        LEFT JOIN
    tablea a ON a.usr_id = b.usr_id
GROUP BY a.usr_id
```

Please advice ?

Comment: please check updated question

Comment: it shows first track of all users , not last track

Comment: Edit war! Whuu!

Comment: Why are not you using `usr_status = 1` in your attempted query ?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya its next case , first need to filter last track on each users , then i can add status